# AJAX не получается вывести на экран данные, пришедшие из удаленного сервера

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

В данном коде идет запрос на удаленный сервер, получаются, обрабатываются и выводятся данные JSON.
Но в данном коде данные приходят, т.к. отображаются в консоли браузера, но так же браузер выдает ошибку:

```
ReferenceError: html is not defined
```

а на экране выдает:

```
[object Object]
```

Хотя, при помощи html (который not defined), я выводил JSON-данные, взятые на локальном сервере и все было нормально...
Помогите разобраться...

script.js:

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            return;
        }
        callback(data);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

ajax_get('http://dev.nexusmedia-ua.com/devtest/', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = data["messages"];

    for (var i=0; i < data["messages"].length; i++) {

        html += '<div><img src="' + data["messages"][i]["image"] + '">' + data["messages"][i]["title"] + "</div>";
        html += '<div>' + data["messages"][i]["name"] + "</div>";
        html += '<div>' + data["messages"][i]["title"] + "</div>";
        html += '<div>' + data["messages"][i]["messages"] + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = html;
});
```

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="messages"></h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="text"></div>

    <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

В функции ajax_get в первом параметре, ссылка переходит на страницу, где храняться следующие данные, представленные в формате JSON:

```
{
 "messages": [
         {
          "image":"https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=300&txt=TT&w=350&h=350",
          "name":"Test User1",
          "title":"CEO & Owner1",
          "message":"Lorem1 ipsum dolor sit amet, has in probo mazim signiferumque..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Не вижу где у вас объявлена переменна `html` в js, к чему вы конкатенируете строки?

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, спасибо Вам